# Is Google support for Chrome in 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 really ending?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

like many others I've had a message when I open Chrome browser to say Chrome won't be supported much longer, with a link to the page telling you 32-bit linux Chrome support is ending, and you need 14.04+.  I have one machine running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04. In the last couple of days it's successfully updated to chrome 49.

Do Google not realise 12.04 had a 64-bit version?  Or will updates eventually come to an end on this machine?

Comment: It has ended as of this week.  All 32 bit Linux and all 12.04 distributions are no longer supported.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome is a 3rd party application. They have their own support cylcle and it is unfortunate it does not match Ubuntu's support cycle. Canonical is not responsible for this browser.

> Do Google not realise 12.04 had a 64-bit version? Or will updates eventually come to an end on this machine?

Yes, they do. The notice they made is not just about 32-bit but also about Ubuntu 12.04:

- Google Chrome is to drop support for all 32-bit Linux distros from March, 2016.
- Google Chrome will also drop support for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (which will receive critical and security bug fixes from Canonical until mid 2017).

It is their choice to kill of the 32-bit version. Probably saved them money and resources so it might even be a logical step.

So if you want to use Chrome and use a version that has all the upgrades your options are to upgrade to 14.04, 15.10 or the upcomming 16.04.

By the way: the browser for Ubuntu is Chromium. Canonical takes care of this browser during the support life cycle of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I was asking - I know Chrome is 3rd party, and about Chromium (which I've installed but it just won't launch BTW). What prompted my query was, with all the noise about the error messages Chrome has caused, have they ended support now?  I don't have a 32-bit version on any of my laptops, so don't know if 32-bit has been updated to Chrome 49.  Guess I'll find out soon enough if/when Google stop providing updates to my 12.04 64-bit version (it's still March after all...)

Comment: So today Chrome updated again...to 49.0.2623.87...despite the message I've had when I open Chrome to say it won't update.  So it is still - at the moment - updating my 12.04 64-bit.  I had to make the amend to the ppa file (Chrome List) that seems to have affected everyone, but so far so good...