# 16.10 64 Will the below set of commands install Chrome on previous versions of Ubuntu as well as 16.10 x64?

Tags: 64-bit, 16.10, amd-graphics, amd-processor

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes.

The first command fetches the deb file from web address which isn't changed.

And the second command installs the downloaded deb file which isn't changed either in 16.10.

Comment: Also note that 12.04 and 32-bit are both [no longer supported](http://askubuntu.com/questions/742231/is-google-support-for-chrome-in-64-bit-ubuntu-12-04-really-ending).

Answer (score 0):

The deb file you are downloading from Google will work and install Google Chrome on any version of Ubuntu 64 bit *supported by Google*. Google is known to have dropped support to some older versions of Ubuntu, but you should be fine with the last few years or Ubuntu x64.