# How can I update my browser on 12.04?

Tags: firefox

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) on a HP laptop. However, Firefox is complaining that my browser or OS is unsupported.

I've downloaded a suggested version of the browser, but I don't know how to install it. How can I go about this?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is now five years old. I would *highly* suggest upgrading to 16.04 as soon as possible. Furthermore, come April 2017, we will no longer be able to help with 12.04 and issues therein.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/742231/is-google-support-for-chrome-in-64-bit-ubuntu-12-04-really-ending

Comment: What's the exact message from Firefox?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`?